# Python - How to pass a QSpinBox value together with other parameters to a slot?

Tags: pyqt, pyside, signals-slots, qspinbox

It's quite straightforward to process a `valueChanged` signal of a single `QSpinBox` with a dedicated slot:

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
        self.ui.spinbox.valueChanged.connect(self.slot)

    def slot(self,value):
        print(value)
```

Now imagine I have many spinboxes (e.g. each of them controls some parameter in a different instance of the same class) and would like to use the same slot to process them. I would like to do something like this:

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
        self.ui.spinbox1.valueChanged.connect(lambda: self.slot(1))
        self.ui.spinbox2.valueChanged.connect(lambda: self.slot(2))
        self.ui.spinbox3.valueChanged.connect(lambda: self.slot(3))

    def slot(self,instance_id,value):
        ...
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work because the spinbox value is not passed through the lambda.

So, what is the best way to pass the value if I'd like to use one single slot to process many similar signals?

Comment: `self.ui.spinbox1.valueChanged.connect(lambda value: self.slot(self.ui.spinbox1, value))` but note that you cannot use this in a loop that creates or gets the widgets. In that case, do `for spinbox in spinboxList:` `spinbox.valueChanged.connect(lambda value, spin=spinbox: self.slot(spin, value))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `self.sender` to identify the spinbox and get its value..

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
        self.ui.spinbox1.valueChanged.connect(self.slot)
        self.ui.spinbox2.valueChanged.connect(self.slot)
        self.ui.spinbox3.valueChanged.connect(self.slot)

    def slot(self):
        spinbox = self.sender()
        value = spinbox.value()
```